# What to do when ACF and PACF plots of the residuals show significant lags?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, residuals, acf-pacf

I have a binomial glm modelling a proportional RV against a categorical predictor. The formula looks like this

```
  model_1 <- glm(formula = cbind(PI,FailurePI) ~ Macrophyte,
 data = uluabat_macr_fg, family = quasibinomial(link = log))
```

When I was evaluating the model, I saw that ACF and PACF plots of the residuals had significant lags. The plots are given below.

[[image]

[image]

My question is how can I fix this? How can I define whatever autoregressive structure I should define? Can you please explain in a simple language and, if possible, modify the above formula however needed (with AR structures perhaps)?

Comment: Both the ACF and PACF plots show a significant lag at point 1, however these are very close to non-significance so I would ignore it. Alternatively, from the ACF plot you can see a small seasonality, so maybe try a MA(1) process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user2974951. How exactly can I do that? Can you explain or can you suggest me any resources that I can read?

Comment: After some research I found no way od doing this, so I don't know if this is even a sensible thing to do. Anyway you may want to look at the `lmer` function in the `lme4` package for a mixed model design with some added random effects, maybe those will help in reducing the autocorrelation.